How to use the Dropbox API to upload a LARGE backup
I'm writing a script to copy a large website (29GB compressed) and I cannot seem to get it to upload via the Dropbox API.
curl -T 05-07-2024_11-01PM_files_backup.tar.gz -X POST https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload_session/start --header "Authorization: Bearer secret-key"     --header "Dropbox-API-Arg: {\"close\":false}"     --header "Content-Type: application/octet-stream"     --header "Transfer-Encoding: chunked"

you should use the Dropbox API's upload session endpoints which allow you to upload a file in multiple chunks.  . You have to split the file into manageable chunks and upload each one sequentially.
